# Updating table in SQLPLUS (Stored Procedure Loop with Comma Delimited Column)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Having some trouble writing my stored procedure. Using Oracle 11g

Goal: I want to be able to create separate rows in my table "info_table" from my table "places_table" with the column alternatenames.  Under the column alternatenames from places_table, there is a comma delimited string with multiple alternate names.  I want to create a row for each one of these alternate names in table "info_table".

ex of alternatenames column string:

```
Beijing,Beijingzi,Pei-ching-tzu
```

what I am hoping to achieve

```
ID        Name
100000000 Beijing
100000001 Beijingzi
100000002 Pei-ching-tzu
```

Currently my code looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE INFO_TABLE
(
    INFOID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR2(500),
    LANGUAGE VARCHAR2(40),
    STATUS VARCHAR2(50),
    COUNTRY_CODE CHAR (10),
    COUNTRY_CODE_2 CHAR (10),
    GID CHAR(10),
    SUPPLIERID CHAR(10),
    LAST_MODIFIED CHAR(50)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE INFO_COUNTER
START WITH 100000000;

CREATE PROCEDURE LOAD_ALTERNATE_NAMES(ALTERNATENAMES_COLUMN VARCHAR2)
AS
COMMA_FINDER NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
    IF ALTERNATENAMES_COLUMN IS NOT NULL
THEN
    <<SEPARATE_ALTERNATENAMES>> WHILE COMMA_FINDER!=0 LOOP
        INSERT INTO INFO_TABLE
        (INFOID, NAME, LANGUAGE, STATUS, COUNTRY_CODE, COUNTRY_CODE_2, GID, SUPPLIERID, LAST_MODIFIED)
        VALUES
        (INFO_COUNTER, SUBSTR(ALTERNATENAMES_COLUMN, INSTR(P.ALTERNATENAMES, ',', COMMA_FINDER+1)), NULL, 'ALTERNATE', P.COUNTRY_CODE, P.COUNTRY_CODE_2, P.GID, NULL, P.LASTMODIFIED)
        FROM INFO_TABLE I, PLACES_TABLE P;
    COMMA_FINDER := INSTR(ALTERNATENAMES, ',', COMMA_FINDER);

    END LOOP SEPARATE_ALTERNATENAMES;

    COMMA_FINDER:=1;

ENDIF;

END
/
```

```
LOAD_ALTERNATE_NAMES(SELECT ALTERNATENAMES FROM PLACES_TABLE);
```

currently the problem is that my INSERT statement in my loop is giving me "SQL Statement Ignored" and I am not sure why.  I have taken a look at the stored procedure and loop documentation but can't figure out if I am doing something wrong or there is a typo.

can someone help me please?

Thank you in advance,

Norman

Comment: ARGH! Why do people insist on making their work much more difficult than it has to be??? Just a touch of normalization will make all your problems go away. Despite what some crazed DBA might say, normalization is NOT evil!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INSERT statement has either the form:

```
INSERT INTO table (...) VALUES (...)
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO table (...) SELECT ... FROM ...
```

That's why Oracle issues an error message.

But there's more. You pass the ALTERNATENAMES string value to the stored procedure but need more data from the PLACES_TABLE. Furthermore, Oracle doesn't support stored procedure calls like this:

```
LOAD_ALTERNATE_NAMES(SELECT ALTERNATENAMES FROM PLACES_TABLE);
```

So I propose you create a stored procedure without parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LOAD_ALTERNATE_NAMES
AS
    COMMA_FINDER NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR REC IN (
        SELECT * FROM PLACES_TABLE WHERE ALTERNATENAMES IS NOT NULL
    ) LOOP
        COMMA_FINDER NUMBER := 1;
        <<SEPARATE_ALTERNATENAMES>> WHILE COMMA_FINDER!=0 LOOP
            INSERT INTO INFO_TABLE
                (INFOID, NAME, LANGUAGE, STATUS, COUNTRY_CODE, COUNTRY_CODE_2, GID, SUPPLIERID, LAST_MODIFIED)
            VALUES
                (INFO_COUNTER.NEXTVAL, SUBSTR(REC.ALTERNATENAMES, INSTR(REC.ALTERNATENAMES, ',', COMMA_FINDER+1)), NULL, 'ALTERNATE', REC.COUNTRY_CODE, REC.COUNTRY_CODE_2, REC.GID, NULL, REC.LASTMODIFIED);

            COMMA_FINDER := INSTR(REC.ALTERNATENAMES, ',', COMMA_FINDER);

        END LOOP SEPARATE_ALTERNATENAMES;

    END LOOP;

END
/
```

I hope that helps you proceed. I haven't test it and I'm afraid that SUBSTR will fail once it reaches the last name. But you'll figure that out.

Comment: thank you for helping me out with the problem.  so far in the progress of working through the answer.  thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little function I use to loop things like you are asking for.  You can specify a delimiter.

The type...

```
type split_array is table of varchar2(32767) index by binary_integer;
```

The function...

```
function split(string_in varchar2, delim_in varchar2) return split_array is

  i       number :=0;
  pos     number :=0;
  lv_str  varchar2(32767) := string_in;
  strings split_array;
  dl number;

begin
  -- determine first chuck of string
  pos := instr(lv_str,delim_in,1,1);
  -- get the length of the delimiter
  dl := length(delim_in);
  if (pos = 0) then --then we assume there is only 1 items in the list. so we just add the delimiter to the end which would make the pos length+1;
    strings(1) := lv_str;
  end if;

  -- while there are chunks left, loop
  while ( pos != 0) loop
     -- increment counter
     i := i + 1;
     -- create array element for chuck of string
     strings(i) := substr(lv_str,1,pos-1);
     -- remove chunk from string
     lv_str := substr(lv_str,pos+dl,length(lv_str));
     -- determine next chunk
     pos := instr(lv_str,delim_in,1,1);
     -- no last chunk, add to array
     if pos = 0 then
        strings(i+1) := lv_str;
     end if;
  end loop;
  -- return array
  return strings;
end split;
```

How to use it...

```
declare

/* alternatenames varchar2(32767) := 'one,two,three,four'; */
nameArray split_array;

begin

    for c1 in ( select alternatenames from yourTable where alternatenames is not null )
    loop

      nameArray := split(c1.alternatenames,',');
      for i in 1..nameArray.count loop
          /* dbms_output.put_line(nameArray(i)); */
          insert into yourTable ( yourColumn ) values ( nameArray(i) );
      end loop;

    end loop;

end;
/
```

Comment: wow thank you for such an amazing function.  I will definitely use this in the future but for this particular inquiry I will still try to use Codo's answer